# Jetty Basic Authentication

Tags: jetty

I am using jetty basic auth to authenticate my application. The problem is that I have to close the browser to clear the authentication. I am looking for a custom code to do the same.

In other words how to logoff/sign off one you have been authenticated by jetty basic auth.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, what I do in Firefox is select "Tools > Clear Recent History", check Active Logins, and click Clear Now. Took me a while to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're asking what I think you're asking, then this is a browser question and not a Jetty question.

It sounds like you simply want a way to get your web-browser to forget your username/password.
How you do that will depend on which browser you are using:

For Chrome [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957822/how-to-clear-basic-authentication-details-in-chrome)
For FireFox try [the Web-developer addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/)
Other browsers will probably have similar solutions.

If you want to do it from within the Jetty server, then that's much harder, but you can start reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668875/how-to-logout-of-auth-basic-authentication-with-htaccess), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233507/how-to-log-out-user-from-web-site-using-basic-authentication), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180206/how-to-force-jetty-to-ask-for-credentials-after-invalidating-the-session/5177191#5177191) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513206/how-to-tell-the-browser-to-forget-htdigest)

Answer (score 0):

Please read this fantastic post on Basic Authentication.
The answer is in the first paragraph.

[How to force Jetty to ask for credentials with BASIC authentication after invalidating the session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180206/how-to-force-jetty-to-ask-for-credentials-after-invalidating-the-session)